# can we put an paid application on itunes which is using opensource libraries?

Tags: itunes

I am just confused about can we put an paid application on itunes which is using open source libraries?

Like if we use XMPPFramework then can we make our application as paid application?

Regards.

Comment: Wow. Sounds like a clear, legitimate question. Why the down vote?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't meant for legal advice.

Comment: Dude, we're not lawyers here, so I suggest you contact one.

Comment: It's an easy answer. Humor him. :)

Comment: @Mannimarco I am not asking Stack Overflow to answer I am here to ask questions from users of Stack Overflow. Thanks for your time to write your comment.

Comment: @Naveed Rafi I do not think your question has anything to do with a specific programming problem; therefore, your question has a high chance of being deleted. Furthermore, we need to keep the questions at SO of high quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the licenses under which you're using/distributing the libraries. If the license for a library allows you to use it in a commercial product, then yes. Read the licenses.

[Here's the page](http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/) for the library. Click on the licensing info in the left tool bar to read it for yourself.

Comment: Great. Thanks. Simple and clear answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great help Jonathan I really appreciate your help. Thank you for being such a nice person. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know the **restrictions of itunes**, but the XMPPFramework is under the New BSD License, which allows your application using it to be sold.

Comment: You mean the XMPPframework of github which is for iphone?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/

Comment: For what did I get a down-vote here??

Comment: I don't know but I gave you +1 :)